# Incrementing Date Variables in a Query and Producing Tabular Results

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to generate a table using a query I've written that increments the date by -1, then reruns the query until the date has decremented to a specified value.

I have tried combinations of while loops and joining two CTE's but I keep running down dead ends.

I've got closest with the first loop here:

```sql
declare @dtime date
set @dtime = getdate()

begin
while @dtime > getdate() -5
(select @dtime as dtime,Partnum,OnHandQty + (sum(TxQty) where TxDate > @dtime) Stock
 where Partnum = x);
(select @dtime = dateadd(day,-1,@dtime)
end
```

However, This just returns repeating values of today's date with a fixed value of Stock which is actually correct for today, but the loop doesnt iterate with decrementing dates.

I then tried using CTE's:

```sql
with CTE_Days as

(select getdate() as dtime
union all
select dtime -1
from CTE_days
where dtime > getdate() -365),

CTE_Inventory as 
(select Partnum,OnHandQty + 
(sum(TxQty) where TxDate > (select dtime from CTE_Days)) Stock
 where Partnum = x),
begin
while (select dtime from CTE_Days) > getdate() -365
select partnum,descrip,plant,dtime,stock
from CTE_Days
cross join CTE_Inventory
order by dtime desc
```

Returns 'subquery returned more than 1 value'.

So I expected a table like this:

```
dtime      |partnum  |Stock
2019-04-25 |x        |10
2019-04-24 |x        |12
2019-04-23 |x        |15
```

Assuming of course that the sum of TxQty between the 24-25 was 2 and between the 23-25 was 5.

I can't see the wood for the trees now, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by the date like this:

```
SELECT dtime, partnum, stock FROM Inventory 
   GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, DTime, 111), partnum, stock
```